# How to generate custom template for sharing contents in instagram stories

Tags: react-native, instagram

I'm working on a React Native app, and I'd like to create a function for sharing contents in Instagram stories, like the tweet below.

How can I generate a custom template, like Twitter does, using Python? Because my backend is written in Django.

[image]

**=== UPDATE ===**

I have done some research and found out that you can use various languages, such as FabricJs or PIL in Python, to draw an image. However, these can be a nightmare for high-complexity stickers. Therefore, my solution is to simply take a screenshot in the app using [react-native-view-shot](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot).

If someone has any better solutions, they would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Websites previews based on website meta tags like [open graph](https://ogp.me/)

You can use this library to generate it https://github.com/tjcages/expo-link-preview.

However, it maybe a better solution is to build these previous on the backend like here https://github.blog/2021-06-22-framework-building-open-graph-images/

And then share image with https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share

Comment: Is it free open graph images from github?

Comment: I don't know it is just an example of an approach to how people do with it. Have you checked https://github.com/tjcages/expo-link-preview it should be enough for your task?

Comment: @PaulRock probably you can take something like this https://github.com/itteco/iframely

Comment: expo-link-preview could be enough but I need to take the images from somewhere, so again it's the same if I took a screenshot and use it.